# How to subtract 2 columns in WHERE condition with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
Trjual_h::where('Kd_Pelanggan', '=', $get)
        ->where('Nilai_Faktur', '-', 'Nilai_Bayar', '>=', '0')
        ->select('Nilai_Faktur', 'Tgl_Faktur', 'Lama_Piutang', 'No_Faktur', 'Nilai_Bayar')
        ->get();
```

I need something like

```sql
Select Nilai_Faktur, Tgl_Faktur, Lama_Piutang, No_Faktur, Nilai_Bayar 
where (Kd_Pelanggan = XXX11) AND (Nilai_Faktur - Nilai_Bayar > 0)
```

But it kept ignoring the two conditions when I run the query, and displaying all available data in my table. Already tried using `DB::raw()` but it keeps giving me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Trjual_h::where('Kd_Pelanggan', $get)
        ->whereRaw('Nilai_Faktur-Nilai_Bayar > 0')
        ->select('Nilai_Faktur','Tgl_Faktur','Lama_Piutang','No_Faktur','Nilai_Bayar')
        ->get();
```

Just a note, I removed the `'='` from `where('Kd_Pelanggan', $get)` as it is not a required parameter when just doing an equals so I always removed it. Works both ways, though.

Answer (score 1):

simply, you can use query builder

```
$clients_due_amount = Client::select(DB::raw('SUM(amount - paid) as due_amount'))->first();
```